# Can the subscriber to topic message in firebase get what it missed as being offline for a couple of minutes

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I had a situation where fcm server send events to specific topics. It works well if the subscribers is online, but if the subscriber went offline for a couple if minutes and in that time the FCM server send events, when the client that was subscribed back to online, it can't get those missed events.

I had a theory that this is because the nature of topics, as there can be multiple subscribers and FCM is not meant to deliver it to every one. It send it on something like a channel and the subscribers fetch it. So best thing here is to send it to specific fcm tokens, so that FCM is meant to deliver the message to them when they are online based on the TTL.

So can any one think my theory is correct, or there is something I missing here?